# Cancelar seleção de Uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer um upload de arquivos `imagens`, porém quando estou clicando no `X` da Preview da foto, ele só está fechando o Preview, porém ainda continua selecionado. Como posso fazer para quando clicar no `x`, também tira-se aquela imagem de lista?

Meu código JS logo abaixo.

```
    <script>
 window.onload = function(){

    //Check File API support
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");

        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("result");

            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];

                //Only pics
                if(!file.type.match('image'))
                  continue;

                var picReader = new FileReader();

                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                    var picFile = event.target;

                    var div = document.createElement("div");

                    div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/> <a href='#' class='remove_pict del'><i class=\"icon-remove\"></i></a>";

                    output.insertBefore(div,null);   
                    div.children[1].addEventListener("click", function(event){
                       div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
                    });         

                });

                 //Read the image
                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }                               

        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Já testaste com `files.value = '';`?

Comment: Não testei, mais como ficaria ? @Sergio

Comment: Renan, de qual lista você diz que deveria ser tirado também?

Comment: ?? não entende sua pergunta.

Comment: Da sua pergunta: *Como posso fazer para quando clicar no `x` também tira-se aquela imagem de **lista**?* - A qual *lista* você se refere? (Observação fora do escopo: Ao responder um comentário, coloque @nomeDoUsuario, assim ele é notificado da sua réplica: no meu caso seria @falsarella).

Comment: É java ou javascript?

Comment: javscript. @GuilhermeNascimento porem ja solucionei.

Comment: Renan então formule uma resposta, ela pode ser útil a outros usuários.

Comment: Ok irei formular, assim que voltar a trabalhar neste projeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente no trecho do evento em que vc remove a imagem:

```js
div.children[1].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    filesInput.value = '';
});
```